# Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp : Sandbox Configuration

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, integration, whatsapp

Please assist

I accidentally deleted my webhook "to this URL when a message comes in" for sandbox configuration for WhatsApp.

Is there a way to regenerate another webhook url HTTP Post.

Please assist.

Please see attachment[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the default url for Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp,  Sandbox Configuration? https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox

If yes, the URL is something like this:

`https://foo-bar-1234.twil.io/whatsapp-respond`

To find your `"foo-bar-1234"` sub-domain just create a Twilio function and take it from the function's PATH, it's the same.

To create a function go to https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage and click on the plus sign. A blank function is fine, you can delete the function after you look at the function's path.